# Find non-overlapping ranges with largest total sum of lengths

Tags: algorithm

I search algorithm, that will help me in the realization of a problem!
The problem is as follows:

There is a list of ranges, I need to build a list with a subset of non-overlapping ranges (not necessarily adjacent), such that the sum of their lengths is maximum possible.

For example, for an input list

> [(-1, 3), (2, 4), (0, 5), (-4, -1)]

the desired output is

> [(0, 5), (-4, -1)]

with the sum of lengths (5 - 0) + ((-1) - (-4)) = 5 + 3 = 8

Comment: What is 'a maximum value'? What value do you want to maximize?

Comment: The sum of the range of intervals

Comment: What sum? What is the 'sum' in example [(1,2), (4,6)]: is it 3=[2-1]+[6-4] or 5=[6-1]...?

Comment: He meant the difference between the min/max values of an interval list (3 - (-4)) in this case

Comment: I meant [(1,2), (4,6)] -> [2-1]+[6-4] = 3

Comment: the total length of the ranges, in short.

Comment: Karoly Horvath, yes) Sorry for my English

Comment: @Treycos In *this* case it was pretty ambiguous, because the intervals have a common end, so sum of the intervals lengths *equals* their total span. That's why I asked about another example, with a hole.

Comment: @deniska369 Okay, so if you meant [(1,2), (4,6)] -> [2-1]+[6-4] = 3, then why is your example result [(-1, 3), (-4, -1)] with the sum of 7, instead of [(0, 5), (-4, -1)]  with the sum of 8...?!

Comment: Intervals do not necessarily need to have a common beginning or end. I just need to keep only those intervals that do not intersect and it is maximum the total length of the ranges.

Comment: CiaPan, =( I mistake. Yes,  [(0, 5), (-4, -1)] is true!

Comment: @deniska369 I have edited your question a bit, please verify if the new version correctly reflects your needs.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, thank you very much!

Comment: Similar problem: [Maximum sum of the range non-overlapping intervals in a list of Intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262121/maximum-sum-of-the-range-non-overlapping-intervals-in-a-list-of-intervals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the maximum weighted independent set problem with the weights being equal to the length of the intervals.

This can be solved using dynamic programming. Let the intervals be sorted by starting times.

Then define `DP[I_j]` = maximum weighted set of intervals such that `I_j` is chosen and only intervals previous to `I_j` are considered. This means the intervals intersecting with `I_j` shall not be considered.

```
DP[I_j] = MAX(DP[I_r]) + Wt(I_j)
```

Where `I_r` are the intervals that occur before `I_j`.

The time complexity is `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of intervals.